# PHP: Mapping name parts from name-parser (theiconic) to vCard properties

Tags: php, parsing, vcf-vcard

I am faced with the situation of converting a string of name data `$realName` into (the correct) vCard properties.

As a parser, the [theiconic name-parser](https://github.com/theiconic/name-parser) seems to be the most suitable for my purposes (the library is currently maintained, is often downloaded, and already takes into account German characteristics).

The source string `$realName` can contain both: names of persons or companies. So its components could (from my pov) therefore be assigned to the following vCard properties:

- FN (string new arranged)
- N (family name [surname]; given name; additional name; honorific prefixes; honorific suffixes)
- NICKNAME (that´s clear)
- ORG

On the other hand, the name-parser provides the following components (or an empty string):

- salutations (e.g. Mr, Mrs, Dr, etc.)
- first name
- middle names
- initials (single letters, and possibly followed by a dot)
- nicknames (parts within parenthesis, brackets etc.)
- last names (ie supports prefixes like from, de etc.)
- suffixes (Jr, Senior, 3rd, PhD, etc.)

According to this - that´s my mapping so far:

```
    /**
     * get an array of name parts vCard property as key
     * 
     * @param string $realname
     * @return array
     */
    function getNameParts(string $realName)
    {
        $parser = new Parser();
        $nameParts = $parser->parse($realName);
        $salutation = $nameParts->getSalutation();
        $firstName  = $nameParts->getFirstname();
        $lastName   = $nameParts->getLastname();
        $middleName = $nameParts->getMiddlename();
        $nickName   = $nameParts->getNickname();
        $initials   = $nameParts->getInitials();
        $suffix     = $nameParts->getSuffix();

        if (!empty($firstName)) {
            $additionalName = implode(',', [$middleName, $initials]);
            $name = implode(';', [$lastName, $firstName, $additionalName, $salutation, $suffix]);
            $fullName = implode(' ', [$salutation, $firstName, $additionalName, $lastName]).', '.$suffix;  
        } else {
            $name = '';
            $fullName = $realName;
            $company = $realName;
        }

        return [
            'N'        => $name,
            'FN'       => $fullName,
            'NICKNAME' => $nickName,
            'ORG'      => $company,
        ]
    }
```

I am not so familiar with the american/english rules for name components, their correct assignment and order (e.g. for FN).
I also have no better idea how to figure out if `$realName` represents a company name or a person.

Therefore, I would like to know if someone else had the same task and could have a look on it if this would go into the right direction.

Many Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have found a satisfactory solution for myself: https://github.com/theiconic/name-parser/pull/40
I hope others can use it.